# Getting some rum into a commerical fruitcake

Tags: baking, cake, dessert

I have purchased an inexpensive (Costco) 1.6kg (3.5lb) fruitcake. Some folks have recommended adding rum to the fruitcake to moisten it up a bit and give it more flavor. Some process involving cheesecloth and inverting the cake was mentioned. I have a bottle of Cuban rum that was gifted to me and I think it might fill the bill.

What is the best process for doing this? At room temperature or in the fridge?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I feed a Christmas cake (home made, but it shouldn't make much difference) I simply prick holes all over it with a thin skewer and drizzle the alcohol over the top. A few days later I invert and do the same on the bottom.  You can repeat a couple of times, 2-3 tablespoons at a time, maximum.

For this I wrap in clingfilm, and store at room temperature in an airtight tin or plastic container.  This works well for the dark, heavy fruit cakes we have as Christmas cakes in the UK (also traditionally used as the bottom tier of wedding cakes).  These cakes keep indefinitely at room temperature so long as they don't dry out.  A lighter fruit cake may end up more soggy than moist.

If it's extra flavour you're after, you could steep some appropriate spices in your rum first: a cinnamon stick, a bit of root ginger and a couple of cloves.  Big pieces rather than ground, so you can pour the rum off them easily, and do this with a small amount so you can taste it and dilute if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

I'm trying to inject rum with one of those turkey injectors.  Using that beautiful Costco cake that doesn't have much taste.  One day the top gets injected, and the next day the bottom gets the same.  I'm keeping it covered with plastic wrap in the original store container, as I think it is air-tight.

Answer (score 0):

A simple technique I have used is to pour some liquor over a cut piece of fruitcake and let it set a few minutes . Not elegant but good. I also prefer bourbon .